# Why can't i use Hashmap directly ,why casting it

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I'm trying to retrieve data from Firebase so I'm using Hashmap for it, but I wanna know why casting Hashmap, why can't use it directly.
Please give a deep and easy language answer (should be in Kotlin)

Here is the code:

```
var map = snapshot.getValue() as Hashmap<String,String>
```

Comment: So you basically ask, why is `as Hashmap<String, String>` needed to be added?

Comment: My question is why "as" why can't i use it without casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When called on a `DataSnapshot` that contains multiple values, `getValue()` returns a `Map<String,Object>` since (while the keys are by definition strings) it can't know what types all of the values in your database are.

If you *know* all the values are strings, you can cast the result to a `Map<String,String>` as you do, but it does require you to cast the result you get back from `getValue()`.

Comment: Thankyou for this simple and understandable answer 

Comment: Okay... actually I'm new here that's why i don't know much about stack ...i see

Answer (score 2):

[DataSnapshot#getValue()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue()) method returns an object of type [Object](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object):

> getValue() returns the data contained in this snapshot as native types. The **possible** types returned are:
>
> - Boolean
> - String
> - Long
> - Double
> - Map<String, Object>
> - List

Since every node in Firebase Realtime Database can be represented by pairs of keys and values, actually Maps, you have to use that cast in order to actually read the data.

Alternativaly, you can use [DataSnapshot#getValue(Class valueType)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getValue(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)) to map each node into an object of a specific class.

**Edit:**

> I studied that getValue() is just an object so can you tell me of which class it's an object?

getValue() returns an object of type [Object](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object). The Object class is the class from which all classes inherit.

> and one more thing if we know some class's object can return a String, Boolean, Map, etc. then every time we need to cast its return type.

Yes, you have to cast to the corresponding value.

> Like in my case I wanna use a map so I cast it to hashmap okay...but if I want to have string value from getValue() then I need to cast it as String right?.

Yes, indeed, this is what you have to do. Or you can use the alternative solution.

Comment: Hey Shivam. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Yes alex,i need a little more help, i studied that getValue() is just an object so can you tell me of which class it's an object ...and one more thing if we know some class's object can return string, Boolean,map etc. then every time we need to cast it's return type ,like in my case i wanna use map so i casted it to hashmap okay...but if i want to have string value from getValue() then i need to cast as String right?.hope you understood my question

Comment: In that case, please check my updated answer. Is clear right now?

Comment: Yes finally it's clear... I can't give reputation now because I'm new but later I'll....and thankyou so much for your efforts sir

Comment: You're very welcome, Shivam. Good to hear that is clear now.